# Getting the rendered value of handlebar template and putting it into a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, sql, wordpress, handlebars.js

```
<script type="text/template" id="ae-profile-loop">

<?php
//This helper snippet takes the JS variables and stores them into the current PHP context
$current_post_ID = "{{= ID }}";
$current_author_ID = "{{= post_author }}";...
```

Context: This is a template .php file (for handlebars.js) located on a server. I'm trying to get $current_author_ID to be the value that is rendered by {{= post_author }}, and not the literal string "{{= post_author }}" itself.

The value is required for executing an SQL query, but it currently doesn't work as if I attempt to pass in $current_author_ID, it uses the literal string instead of the value it rendered.

Any other solutions to pass the rendered value to the php file is welcome.

Comment: Don't post code as images. Copy/paste the code into the question itself.

Comment: edited it to remove the image.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. php runs on server whereas js runs in browser long after php has completed and sent page to browser

Comment: It's a php template that's loaded via AJAX when pagination occurs (on a Wordpress site).